# How to efficiently provide cloned trained models to parallel processes evaluating machine learning models?

Tags: c#, multithreading, machine-learning, parallel-processing

I have a dictionary full of thousands of cases (arrays) of feature data. I use a parallel ForEach loop to run a "Classify" method which adds a tuple containing results (say, an ID number and a classification integer) to a ConcurrentBag. When this works, it works well. But deep inside the Classify method is an Evaluation function which applies a trained model to a set of feature data and returns a classification. I use C# and either a neural network or a decision forest model built using ALGLIB or a similar neural network model built using CNTK for C#. In each case, the trained model file is read into an appropriate object on startup. However, inside the parallel Classify method, a new unique copy of this model is required to be thread-safe for each Evaluation classification operation. I have experimented with several ways of doing this: (1) by using a lock (around the Evaluation statement) or (2) by using a cloning method - for ALGLIB models, this is .make_copy(); for CNTK, it is _clonedModelFunc(). Neither of these methods is very fast and, in fact, for a decision forest model, make_copy() is too slow to be useable.

(3) The best and fastest method, I have found, is to create an array of model clones ahead of time at startup. This leads to my problem and my question. My computer has 4 cores available and with hyperthreading has 8 logical processors. Thus I thought I should be able to run several concurrent threads (7 excluding the waiting main thread). (Actually I am using a Virtualbox with 2 assigned cores and 4 logical processors.) So I create an array of dimension 8 holding 8 cloned copies of my trained model like this:

```
Up in the class constructor:
     ...
     CNTK.Function _CNTK_NN = Function.Load(Globals.CNTK_NN_Pathname, DeviceDescriptor.UseDefaultDevice(), ModelFormat.CNTKv2);
     ...
     for (int i = 0; i < _clonedModelFunc.Count(); i++)    // originally the array was dimensioned [8]
          _clonedModelFunc[i] = _CNTK_NN.Clone(ParameterCloningMethod.Share);
     ...
```

and later used this statement to select which model each thread should be using uniquely like this:

```
Down in a public Classify method:
     ...
     CNTK.Function _NN = _clonedModelFunc[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId];
      ...
     _NN.Evaluate(inputDataMap, outputDataMap, DeviceDescriptor.UseDefaultDevice());
     var outputData = outputDataMap[_label].GetDenseData<float>(_label);
     ...
```

The first time I ran this from Visual Studio in a small test program with a ConsoleWrite($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); statement in the Classify method, all I ever saw were threadID numbers 1 through 7 (MS documentation says 0 is not used). That looked OK and worked fine. However, I got index errors when I placed this within a much larger program. Then I noticed that I was consistently getting threadIDs (still in a range of 7, I think) but with values from, say, 13 to 20 or 18 to 25, etc. My temporary solution has been simply to increase the number of cloned models in the _clonedModelFunc[] array up to 30 or 40. This appears to work fine on my machine and for this particular program.

My question is "How can I tell what core and logical processor I am running a particular parallel instance (a "thread") on?" Obviously Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId is not a very good idea. And, anyway, I think of threads as CPU timeslots which can be many. I need a number based on cores and processors to be able to assign each concurrent instance to a different clonedModel, depending upon the hardware channel it is running within. As soon as that instance finished, a new instance would start, and since it would be running "in the same place," it would be free to reuse that same cloned model. This concept does appear to work well, but I need to limit the number of cloned models that I store ahead of time in memory.

----------------- Edit: A possible answer:

Sometimes asking a question helps one to frame an answer. So here is an apparent solution to my own question here. Perhaps there are flaws but this seems to work.

In my program, in the machine learning model class, I added a small dictionary

```
public interface IClassifier
{
    int PredictStatus(double[] data, int cloneindex = -1);
    (int pstatus, List<double> prob) PredictProb(double[] data, int cloneindex = -1);
}

/// <summary>
/// Choose Machine Learning Classification Method using Globals.EstMethod ENUM value
/// </summary>
public class MLModel : IClassifier
{
    private IClassifier _IClassifierModel;
    // The cloneindex dictionary 
    private Dictionary<int, int> _index = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    private bool _usecloneindex = true;
    object sync = new Object();

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the trained network indicated by ENUM value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mychoice">an EstimationMethod EMUN value</param>
    /// <param name="usecloneindex">DEFAULT: true to use clone index dictionary.<para>
    /// Set false to use threadID for cloned model selection.</para></param>
    public MLModel(EstimationMethod mychoice, bool usecloneindex = true)
    {
        _usecloneindex = usecloneindex;
        switch (mychoice)
        {
            case EstimationMethod.NeuralNetwork:
                _IClassifierModel = new NeuralNetwork(Globals.NeuralNetworkPathname);
                break;

           ... more case statements to select other trained models
```

Then I added a private method to this class, like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Build the clone index dynamically and return current clone index
/// </summary>
/// <returns>current clone index</returns>
private int GetCloneIndex()
{
    int threadnumber = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    if (_index.TryGetValue(threadnumber, out int cloneindex)) { }
    else
    {
        lock (sync)
        { _index.Add(threadnumber, _index.Count() + 1); }
        cloneindex = _index.Count();
    }
    return cloneindex;
}
```

Then, when one of the public model methods is called (while running on the main thread or on concurrent threads), before passing the call to the specific selected machine learning model class method, this GetCloneIndex method is called (as shown below). It gets the current theadID and checks to see if it is already in the _index. If not, it adds that threadID as a key and the increment count of entries as a value. (The method uses a lock, but that only happens 5 or 10 times during the entire run, whenever a new threadID appears.) Whether it was or was not in the dictionary before, the routine returns the associated count value. That value is passed to the machine learning model and used to select the appropriate unique clonedModel from an array field in that class, built by that class's constructor. (I have found that 16 cloned copies of each model is sufficient to avoid indexing problems with my application running on a two-core, 4 processor CPU (and using new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 } in my parallel ForEach loop).

It is worth mentioning again that these are concurrent managed threads on different processors, I think, and not "threads" in the sense of multi-threaded CPU time slots or stacks of such threads.

```
/// <summary>
/// Classify a Bezier History Curve by Status
/// </summary>
/// <param name="array">24 equi-spaced Bezier values from start to end</param>
/// <param name="cloneindex">a default or passed value overidden by the constructor</param>
public int PredictStatus(double[] array, int cloneindex = -1)
{
    if (_usecloneindex == true) cloneindex = GetCloneIndex();
    return _IClassifierModel.PredictStatus(array, cloneindex);
}
```

In general, using pre-prepared ML Model clones is much, much faster than cloning a new copy for each thread instance. But storing a whole bunch of models is memory-expensive (especially for decision forests, etc.). But as long as the threadIDs stay reasonably close in range (say, within a range of 16 - the size I've chosen by trial and error here), the clone index dictionary method will continue to assign the same clone copy to each particular threadID each time it runs on a processor. And that was exactly what I needed to make sure there were no cross-thread issues (i.e., the output of the parallel method is always exactly the same as the output of the method running serially on the main thread.)

I would certainly welcome any feedback readers of this Stack Overflow question might wish to suggest.